# Create file with Inno Setup for InfoBeforeFile

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create a file with Inno Setup to use for InfoBeforeFile. How could I do this?

thanks
Michael

Comment: Use notepad or your favorite text editor and save the file in a plain text file with the *.txt extension, or create an RTF file with *.rtf extension. If you save such file into the same directory as your *.iss script is saved, you can specify only the file name to the `InfoBeforeFile` directive, otherwise specify the file name with the absolute path there.

Comment: thanks, I would like to create the file automatically. 
Is there a way with inno-setup?

Comment: Yes, there is. But what is the source for that generating ? And in which format (RTF is more difficult to generate) ?

Comment: I have a *.ini file, which I read with the preprocessing. The txt format is a good solution.